# Como dar refresh em uma bootstrap-table após dar update?

Tags: javascript, html, mvc, bootstrap-3, table

Seguinte, nas linhas da minha tabela do `bootstrap` quando eu clico abre um `modal` onde eu posso alterar a informação selecionada após clique. Eu queria que logo após eu ter clicado no botão pra alterar, a minha tabela (e só ela) atualizasse sem eu precisar dar um "`refresh` na página toda". Tentei com o `Javascript` abaixo mas não acontece nada.

```js
var dados = [];
var $myModal = $('#myModal');
var btnAltera = $('#btn-altera');
var $table = $('#table-forms');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('/Formulario/SelecionarFormularios', function(data){
        if (data != null){
            var Formularios = data.data;
            $.each(Formularios, function (i, data) {
                var forms = {
                    id: data.IdFormulario,
                    idempresa: data.IdEmpresa,
                    nomeform: data.NomeFormulario,
                    nomeempresa: data.Empresa.Nome,
                    logopath: data.Empresa.LogoPath,
                }
                dados.push(forms);
            });
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        $table.bootstrapTable({
            data: dados,
            pagination: true,
            pageSize: 10,
            search: true,
            showRefresh: true,
            showExport: true,
            sidePagination: 'client',
            dataClickToSelect: true,
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'ID',
                    field: 'id',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    title: 'IDEMPRESA',
                    field: 'idempresa',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    title: 'NOME FORMULÁRIO',
                    field: 'nomeform',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    title: 'EMPRESA',
                    field: 'nomeempresa',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
                {
                    title: 'LOGO-URL',
                    field: 'logopath',
                    align: 'center',
                    sortable: true,
                },
            ]
        }).on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
            $('#id').val(row.id);
            $('#nomeform').val(row.nomeform);
            $('#nomeempresa').val(row.nomeempresa);
            $('#empresamodal').val(row.nomeempresa);
            $('#logopath').val(row.logopath);

            var BotstrapDialog = $myModal;

            BotstrapDialog.modal({
                show: 'false'
            });

            btnAltera.click(function () {
                AlterarFormulario();
                $table.bootstrapTable('refresh', {
                    url: '/Formulario/Formulario'
                });
            });
        });
    }, 200);

    function AlterarFormulario() {
        $.post('/Formulario/AlterarFormulario', {
            IdFormulario: $('#id').val(),
            NomeFormulario: $('#nomeform').val(),
        });
    }
});
```

*Html:*

```
<div class="row">
    <table id="table-forms" class="table table-bi table-hover" style="table-layout:auto;">
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Como você altera esses dados, eles vão para qual lugar, uma variável um banco de dados como você trabalha essa informação. A atualização também deveria ser chamada quando fecha o modal e não no mesmo tempo que ele abre ...

Comment: Então estou usando o método mvc... Então eu chamo uma action na controller que criei para atualizar e ai manda pro SQLServer com json e tal...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolvido de forma alternativa...

location.reload();   <- No JavaScript, após clicar no botão.

Answer (score 1):

Nesse seu escopo, eu faria da seguinte forma:

**Escopo ta dabela:**

```
<tr id="row_12">
  <td class="htmlCampo1">...
  <td>
  <td class="htmlCampo2">...
  <td>
  <td class="htmlCampo3">...
  <td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  btnAltera.click(function () {
    if (AlterarFormulario(row_12 //row que quer alterar)) { //se retornar true; 

      //crie uma funcao que pegue os valores dos campos do modal e insira na tabela
      funcAltera(row, campo1, campo2, campo3...);
    }
  });
});
```

**Função que vai mudar os dados na row**

```
function funcAltera(row, campo1, campo2, campo3...) {
    $("#" + row + " td.htmlCampo1").html(campo1);
    $("#" + row + " td.htmlCampo2").html(campo2);
    $("#" + row + " td.htmlCampo3").html(campo3);    
}
```

Comment: Opa desculpa amigo esqueci de informar que eu altero no banco de dados com json e tal... to usando mvc. Eu precisava que a tabela desse um refresh pra mostrar o que eu altero com o modal...

Comment: Se é com MVC, por que você não cria uma view só com sua tabela e carrega ela sempre via ajax?
Assim você tem uma action específica pra fazer o que quiser com a view.
Coloque uma div onde está sua tabela e carrega essa view via ajax. 
Sempre que chamar a url dessa sua tabela, ela virá atualizada.

Ex: 
Se atualizar os dados, faça um $.ajax da url da tabela para a div que está apontando a tabela.
Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi sim mano, mas não consegui fazer. Então ao invés de dar refresh   optei pelo reload na página toda mesmo. Mas valeu !